# In Ext.tree.TreePanel, when we load the tree, there in no event to check if ALL the tree-nodes are completely loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, recursion, tree, asp.net-ajax

In Ext.tree.TreePanel, when we load the tree, there in no event to check if ALL the tree-nodes are completely loaded.

What we do is, we recursively make asynchronous calls and let the node expands per the node having expanded property to true. How can we find all the asyc. calls has completed and the treePanel is loaded completly ?

The idea behind is when the nodes of treepanel completely loaded then we have to enable a button representing that the tree is available for end user for further operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your input @JuHwon. However, your was not suited well in that scenario. Because the Ajax calls were out of the box, As I mentioned the tree triggers call based on a property(may be isSelectable = true, as far as I can recall now). So, for fulfilling this use case I have used setTimeOut and clearTimeOut method for dynamically push a delay of 2000 ms. I didn't find more closer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Ajax.request(...) returns an object and if that object contains an xhr property the request is not completed.

```
var req = Ext.Ajax.request(..);

if(!req.xhr)
   //request is finished
else 
   // request is not finished
```

Though i would recommend to return a total count of your nodes with every request. So i'd return a json like this:

```
{
    data: [...], // treenodes
    totalCount: 100
}
```

now you can check in every request success function if your treestore already contains all nodes.